# HTML | JS Отображение количества использованных символов в строке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть модальное окно с текстовой строкой для добавления задания. Для длинны задания есть ограничение в 70 символов. Я написал маленький скрипт

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#TaskNameInput', function () {
    input = $("#TaskNameInput").val().length;
    document.getElementById("taskNameCharacterCounter").innerText = (70-input) + " of 70 characters avaliable";
});
```

Первое, что я заметил это когда пишешь певрый символ, то длинна переменной `input` все равно равна 0, однако все равно в конце показывает, что занято все 70 символов. И почему-то данный код также не работает когда стираешь символы.

Как можно было бы это исправить?
Как можно было бы это исправить?

Comment: В метках у вас указана Java. Может всё же javascript?

Comment: @Pashok, ой да извините, не доглядел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const count = document.querySelector('p b');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
 count.innerHTML = this.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<p>Кол-во символов: <b>0</b></p>
```

Comment: Вопрос к знающим, если использовать стрелочную конструкцию: `() => {}` то как получить `this.value` ? Вопрос не относится к данной теме, просто интересно как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Ответ простой - никак :) Можно через `event.target`, конечно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо, думал есть какое-то решение, тогда нужно грамотно использовать стрелочную и обычную форму записи чтобы не было данных казусов